# SKSpriteNode creation with static methods and properties

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

**Hi, guys!**

I'am writing game with SpriteKit framework and I try to make object with several configurations so I have to use static to avoid init method and some boilerplate code with decoder. So I wrote code but I'am not really know if this code is acceptable for creation purpose or not but this code actually works fine.

```
class Island: SKSpriteNode {

    static func populateIsland(at point: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {
        let islandImageName = configureIslandName()
        let island = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: islandImageName)
        island.setScale(randomScaleFactor)
        island.position = point

        return island
    }

    fileprivate static func configureIslandName() -> String {
        let distribution = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 4)
        let randomNumber = distribution.nextInt()
        let imageName = "pic" + "\(randomNumber)"
        return imageName
    }

    fileprivate static var randomScaleFactor: CGFloat {
        let distribution = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 7, highestValue: 10)
        let randomNumber: CGFloat = CGFloat(distribution.nextInt()) / 10

        return randomNumber
    }
}
```

So actual example is:

```
let island = Island.populateIsland(at: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
```

Thank you for your suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is totally fine.

Static members are used when they are not related to instances of a type, but to the type itself. Since your methods just create and return an `SKSpriteNode`, it does not need any state and thus, can be independent from instances of the `Island` type.

I also think that you should rename some of your member names to fit the Swift 3 API guidelines and also to make their purpose clearer. e.g. `populateIslands(atPosition:)` does not really "populate" islands. It just creates *one* single island sprite and returns it. I suggest you to rename it to `createIsland(at:)`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You're right, I've just made quick change to post it here so a little miss from me. Now i'am thinking how to  attach instance methods to instance itself because it is just SKSpriteNode :)

Comment: @wm.p1us What do you mean "attack instance methods to instance itself"? Do you mean "attach"? Instance methods attach to instances by itself, you don't need to do anything.